# Using jQuery to get text from a link instead of the href

Tags: jquery

I have the following piece of code which gets the url from a link but i want to get the title of the link instead, any ideas ?

Thanks.

```
$(this).wrapInner('<span data-title="'+($(this).attr('href'))+'"></span>');
```

The html for a link would look something like this :

```
<a href="#link-effect-2"><span data-hover="Ironman">Ironman</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).wrapInner('<span data-title="' + $(this).text() + '"></span>');
```